# AngularJS + GitHub API - get public & private repositories using personal access token

Tags: angularjs, github-api

I am trying to use an AngularJS controller with `$http` to access the GitHub API. For the sake of testing, I have created a Personal Access Token on GitHub with full access to my account, which I will denote `ghp_MASTER_TOKEN`.

I would like to obtain all of my repositories, both public and private, from my account. My understanding is that, before an update, this could be done by running a simple request,

```
$http.get( "https://api.github.com/users/mwhicks-dev/repos?access_token=ghp_MASTER_TOKEN" )
        .then( function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
});
```

However, due to this being [deprecated](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/), I now must submit my token from within headers. I attempt to do this as follows:

```
$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'https://api.github.com/users/mwhicks-dev/repos',
    headers : {
        'Authorization' : 'token ghp_MASTER_TOKEN'
    }
}).then( function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
});
```

however, when I do this, only my public repositories are logged still. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried every combination of:

- `token MASTER_TOKEN`
- `ghp_MASTER_TOKEN`
- `MASTER_TOKEN`

as the parameter of `Authorization`.